# Badge suggestion: badges for total number of favorites across your questions

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request, bookmarks

I would like to propose a badge given to a user, when he/she has gained a *cumulative* number of favorites on their questions.

I believe there should be several versions of the badge i.e. bronze, silver and gold and I would suggest the names Sheriff (first favourite), Superstar (50 favourites) and Galaxy (200 stars). Maybe those values need to be tweaked as maybe these limits are too easy to achieve. As a user may favourite his/her own question I believe such stars should not count for these badges.

I am making this proposal as I feel that having a lot of your questions favorited by someone means (in my opinion) that your contributions are "exceptionally" helpful and definitely deserve some more bonuses that the current Stellar Question and Favorite Question badges.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you misunderstand what he is asking.  He wants badges for cumulative favorites by a user over many different questions.  __Not a dupe__.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but my idea is to give a badge if **total amount** of stars exceeds a given limit. Not a single question. Somewhat equivellent to tag badges and great answer badge for instance.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Ah, okay, retracting in that case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, good edit.

Comment: There's a problem here, not everyone favourites a question because it's good. I mostly favourite questions to keep an eye on them when something bad is happening (but not bad enough for me to intervene) for example. The name is a bit misleading, bookmarks would be more accurate.

Comment: I don't think one favorite should get anything, heck you can favorite your own question.

Comment: @Yannis, I agree, though usually (on SO, not Meta) it's because there is good content in one of the answers.

Comment: @Yannis that is the terminology used for Favorite and Stellar question badges. For instance: `Question favorited by 25 users` truth is though, I really use this feature to bookmark.

Comment: @izomorphius I'm not debating the terminology, I'm saying that having a lot of your questions favorited by someone doesn't necessarily mean your contributions are exceptionally helpful.

Comment: @Yannis for me bookmarking a question means that either the question or the answers are helpful for a user. In both cases this is content in the community that is helpful and is triggered by the user asking the question.

Comment: Yes, I get that's what bookmarking a question means for you, just saying that it doesn't mean the same for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure we really need these, but I would suggest these names:

- Favorite User - Has 100 favorite stars on questions
- Stellar User - Has 500 favorite stars on questions

I don't think we need a bronze level for this, we should mostly parallel the Question badges with some different numbers.

Comment: **If** this were to be implemented it'd need a minimum number of questions too. No 'Favorite User' for just one question being starred a massive number of times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, agreed, though I agree with Yannis that having favorited questions doesn't mean the user actually contributed that much.  It might be better if we were able to favorite answers.

Comment: I quite agree with Yannis on this too; hence my bolded **if**.

Comment: Maybe like 500+ stars with at least 10 question with at least 10+ stars (something along that pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this community is so successsful thanks to two kinds of users - the ones that give great answers and the ones that ask the right questions.

Though I agree with Yannis that the may reason a user favourites a question is that he wants to bookmark it, this still means "I want to be able to return here later". So either the question or one or more of the answers are something the user finds helpful. I believe that if the question triggered an answer that is helpful to you, then the question is also helpful.

For users that answer questions there are the tag badges - you pile up all the upvotes you have for a given area and you get a badge for that. On the other hand there is no such thing for "askers".

As pointed out in comments I believe there should also be a limit - for instance count up to 10 stars for a question. We should also consider that you are focused only on a given area for a tag badge, while stars are "tag-independent", so the number of stars probably has to be more than votes for a tag badge. On the other hand usually favourites are way less than both the upvotes of the answers and the question.

So my suggestion is to have only two versions - a silver and a gold version and to have the silver version for 100 stars and the gold version for 400 stars.